# Could you name some apis to upload image with react with for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I have already used imgur api but after some usage it is giving 429 error type too many requests

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you just simulate the image uploading behavior for testing purposes (delay 500ms after clicking upload and then returning some pre-defined image URL)? I think that upload itself it's not important for you during development process.

Comment: I want to use it for preview purposes and have some idea how the server will respond

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion for the best API for testing and also production Unsplash is the best API. I don't know which language you are using but Unsplash provides a library for specific Languages so you easily used them.

API Doc: https://unsplash.com/documentation
Specific Language Library: https://unsplash.com/documentation#libraries--sdks

I hope this API will you use.

Comment: If I may ask, how is Unsplash the best API? Aren't they just a stock photo company?